# Can "list_display" in a Django ModelAdmin display attributes of ForeignKey fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, modeladmin

I have a `Person` model that has a foreign key relationship to `Book`, which has a number of fields, but I'm most concerned about `author` (a standard CharField).

With that being said, in my `PersonAdmin` model, I'd like to display `book.author` using `list_display`:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['book.author',]
```

I've tried all of the obvious methods for doing so, but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 661, accepted):

As another option, you can do lookups like:

```
#models.py
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'get_author')
    
    def get_author(self, obj):
        return obj.book.author
    get_author.short_description = 'Author'
    get_author.admin_order_field = 'book__author'
```

Since Django 3.2 you can use [`display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#the-display-decorator) decorator:

```
#models.py
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'get_author')
    
    @admin.display(ordering='book__author', description='Author')
    def get_author(self, obj):
        return obj.book.author
```

Comment: Shouldn't both be `get_author`, since that is what the string you're returning (and the short description) actually reference?  Or change string format argument to `obj.book.reviews`?

Comment: @AnatoliyArkhipov, there is a way (based on [Terr answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3351431/)). I've already updated the code in this answer.

Comment: why can't you just have `author = ForeignKey(Author)` in the book model, and then `list_display = ('author')`?

Comment: Gah, I accidentally clicked downvote instead of upvote and it won't let me change it unless the answer is edited. :( Sorry.

Comment: @alias51: because the user is not linked to an author, but to a book, and the book is linked to an author?

Comment: This causes one query per row displayed in the admin :(

Comment: @marcelm that’s what `select_related` is for. the `get_queryset()` of the `UserAdmin` will have to be overwritten.

Comment: For Django Version > 3.2, please refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67746847/11605100

Comment: The display decorator is defined as `@admin.display(....)`

Comment: What's the use of ellipsis`...` before `'get_author'`?

Comment: @dark_prince, I think that's meant to suggest other fields in the list display in this example, it's not actual code you would execute.

Comment: Can something similar be done except that a) it's displayed in the details view, i.e. not list_display=[...] but fields=[...], and b) what's displayed is a link to the detail page of the related object?

Answer (score 203):

Despite all the great answers above and due to me being new to Django, I was still stuck.  Here's my explanation from a very newbie perspective.

**models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**admin.py (Incorrect Way)** - you think it would work by using 'model__field' to reference, but it doesn't

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
    list_display = ['title', 'author__name', ]

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

**admin.py (Correct Way)**  - this is how you reference a foreign key name the Django way

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
    list_display = ['title', 'get_name', ]

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return obj.author.name
    get_name.admin_order_field  = 'author'  #Allows column order sorting
    get_name.short_description = 'Author Name'  #Renames column head

    #Filtering on side - for some reason, this works
    #list_filter = ['title', 'author__name']

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

For additional reference, see the Django model link [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#list-display)

Comment: for order field shouldn't it be =  'author__name' ?

Comment: This works perfectly, however I am unsure why. `obj` is `BookAdmin`?

Comment: Wow. Took me an hour on the web to find this. This should be made a lot clearer in the Django documentation

Comment: Thanks @Will. Do you realize that for list_display, [..., 'get_name', ] has to be assigned but for search_field, it does not work, instead, [..., 'author__name', ] has to be assigned?  It seems counter-intuitive for me, isn't it?

Answer (score 74):

Like the rest, I went with callables too. But they have one downside: by default, you can't order on them. Fortunately, there is a solution for that:

## Django >= 1.8

```
def author(self, obj):
    return obj.book.author
author.admin_order_field  = 'book__author'
```

## Django < 1.8

```
def author(self):
    return self.book.author
author.admin_order_field  = 'book__author'
```

Comment: method signature should be `def author(self, obj):`

Comment: Back when I made the comment it wasn't the case but it appears that since version 1.8 the method gets the object passed to it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Depends whether you define it on the admin or the model, eh

Answer (score 74):

Please note that adding the `get_author` function would slow the list_display in the admin, because showing each person would make a SQL query.

To avoid this, you need to modify `get_queryset` method in PersonAdmin, for example:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super(PersonAdmin,self).get_queryset(request).select_related('book')
```

> Before: 73 queries in 36.02ms (67 duplicated queries in admin)
>
> After: 6 queries in 10.81ms

Comment: This is really important and should always be implemented

Comment: This is important indeed. Alternatively, if one were to go down the `__str__` route, just add the foreignkey to `list_display` and `list_select_related`

Comment: "list_select_related" is the best solution to the title question

Answer (score 41):

## For Django >= 3.2

The proper way to do it with Django 3.2 or higher is by using the [display decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.display)

```py
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
    list_display = ['title', 'get_author_name']

    @admin.display(description='Author Name', ordering='author__name')
    def get_author_name(self, obj):
        return obj.author.name
```

Answer (score 24):

According to the documentation, you can only display the `__unicode__` representation of a ForeignKey:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#list-display

Seems odd that it doesn't support the `'book__author'` style format which is used everywhere else in the DB API.

Turns out there's [a ticket for this feature](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5863), which is marked as Won't Fix.

Comment: @Mermoz really? It appears the ticket remains set as wontfix. It doesn't appear to work, either (Django 1.3)

Comment: 1.11 still doesn't exist. Been doing django for a dozen years and I never remember this one :(

Answer (score 13):

I just posted a snippet that makes admin.ModelAdmin support '__' syntax:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2887/

So you can do:

```
class PersonAdmin(RelatedFieldAdmin):
    list_display = ['book__author',]
```

This is basically just doing the same thing described in the other answers, but it automatically takes care of (1) setting admin_order_field (2) setting short_description and (3) modifying the queryset to avoid a database hit for each row.

Comment: I like this idea a lot, but it doesn't seem to work anymore with recent django verions: `AttributeError: type object 'BaseModel' has no attribute '__metaclass__'`

Answer (score 12):

There is a very easy to use package available in PyPI that handles exactly that: [django-related-admin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-related-admin). You can also [see the code in GitHub](https://github.com/PetrDlouhy/django-related-admin).

Using this, what you want to achieve is as simple as:

```
class PersonAdmin(RelatedFieldAdmin):
    list_display = ['book__author',]
```

Both links contain full details of installation and usage so I won't paste them here in case they change.

Just as a side note, if you're already using something other than `model.Admin` (e.g. I was using `SimpleHistoryAdmin` instead), you can do this: `class MyAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin, RelatedFieldAdmin)`.

Comment: getter_for_related_field doesn't work in 1.9 so It seems to be not the best choice to those who likes customizing.

Comment: This library is up to date and works great for us here on Django 3.2

Answer (score 11):

You can show whatever you want in list display by using a callable. It would look like this:

```
def book_author(object):
  return object.book.author

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = [book_author,]
```

Comment: This one is nice for situations, where a lot of different models often call to same attribute; is it supported in 1.3+?

Comment: The problem about this is the amount of SQL queries done in the end. For each object in the list, it will make a query. This is why 'field__attribute' would be very handy, because certainly Django would span that to one SQL query only. Odd that there is no support this already.

Answer (score 6):

This one's already accepted, but if there are any other dummies out there (like me) that didn't immediately get it from the [presently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/164631/58668), here's a bit more detail.

The model class referenced by the `ForeignKey` needs to have a `__unicode__` method within it, like here:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

That made the difference for me, and should apply to the above scenario.  This works on Django 1.0.2.

Comment: On python 3 this would be `def __str__(self):`.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a lot of relation attribute fields to use in `list_display` and do not want create a function (and it's attributes) for each one, a dirt but simple solution would be override the `ModelAdmin` instace `__getattr__` method, creating the callables on the fly:

```py
class DynamicLookupMixin(object):
    '''
    a mixin to add dynamic callable attributes like 'book__author' which
    return a function that return the instance.book.author value
    '''

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if ('__' in attr
            and not attr.startswith('_')
            and not attr.endswith('_boolean')
            and not attr.endswith('_short_description')):

            def dyn_lookup(instance):
                # traverse all __ lookups
                return reduce(lambda parent, child: getattr(parent, child),
                              attr.split('__'),
                              instance)

            # get admin_order_field, boolean and short_description
            dyn_lookup.admin_order_field = attr
            dyn_lookup.boolean = getattr(self, '{}_boolean'.format(attr), False)
            dyn_lookup.short_description = getattr(
                self, '{}_short_description'.format(attr),
                attr.replace('_', ' ').capitalize())

            return dyn_lookup

        # not dynamic lookup, default behaviour
        return self.__getattribute__(attr)


# use examples    

@admin.register(models.Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, DynamicLookupMixin):
    list_display = ['book__author', 'book__publisher__name',
                    'book__publisher__country']

    # custom short description
    book__publisher__country_short_description = 'Publisher Country'


@admin.register(models.Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, DynamicLookupMixin):
    list_display = ('name', 'category__is_new')

    # to show as boolean field
    category__is_new_boolean = True
```

As [gist here](https://gist.github.com/cauethenorio/9db40c59cf406bf328fd)

Callable especial attributes like `boolean` and `short_description` must be defined as `ModelAdmin` attributes, eg `book__author_verbose_name = 'Author name'` and `category__is_new_boolean = True`.

The callable `admin_order_field` attribute is defined automatically.

Don't forget to use the [list_select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related) attribute in your `ModelAdmin` to make Django avoid aditional queries.

Comment: Just tried this with a Django 2.2 install & it worked great for me while other approaches did not, for whatever reason.  Note that nowadays you need to import reduce from functools or elsewhere...

Answer (score 6):

I may be late, but this is another way to do it. You can simply define a method in your model and access it via the `list_display` as below:

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_book_author(self):
        return self.book.author
```

**admin.py**

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_book_author',)
```

But this and the other approaches mentioned above add two extra queries per row in your listview page. To optimize this, we can override the `get_queryset` to annotate the required field, then use the annotated field in our ModelAdmin method

**admin.py**

```
from django.db.models.expressions import F

@admin.register(models.Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_author',)
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            _author = F('book__author')
        )
        return queryset

    @admin.display(ordering='_author', description='Author')
    def get_author(self, obj):
        return obj._author
```

Answer (score 5):

if you try it in Inline, you wont succeed unless:

in your inline:

```
class AddInline(admin.TabularInline):
    readonly_fields = ['localname',]
    model = MyModel
    fields = ('localname',)
```

in your model (MyModel):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    localization = models.ForeignKey(Localizations)

    def localname(self):
        return self.localization.name
```

Answer (score -1):

AlexRobbins' answer worked for me, except that the first two lines need to be in the model (perhaps this was assumed?), and should reference self:

```
def book_author(self):
  return self.book.author
```

Then the admin part works nicely.

Answer (score -5):

I prefer this:

```
class CoolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('pk', 'submodel__field')

    @staticmethod
    def submodel__field(obj):
        return obj.submodel.field
```