# Display parent fields in childs admin (list_display)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Here is a snippet of models.py

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    email = models.CharField(...)

class Application(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicant)
    text = models.TextField(...)
```

Here is my admin.py:

```
class ApplicationAdmin(model.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['text', *******]

admin.site.register(Application, ApplicationAdmin)
```

**In the ApplicationAdmin I want to present the Applicants name and email.**

*What have you tried before asking SO?*
I have looked at the following code, which **does not** work:

```
list_display = ['text', 'applicant__name','applicant__email']
```

I have looked at [ModelAdmin.inlines](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin) but as one can see, the parent/child relationship have to be reversed.

Any suggestions? How can I display an applicants name/email in Applications admin. Prefferably without migrating the database with new fields etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "list\_display" in a Django ModelAdmin display attributes of ForeignKey fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it like the fourth possibility in the [list_display docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display). Just add a method to your Application model like so:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicant)
    text = models.TextField(...)

    def applicant_name(self):
        return self.applicant.name
    applicant_name.short_description = 'Applicant Name'

    def applicant_email(self):
        return self.applicant.email
    applicant_email.short_description = 'Applicant Email'
```

And then you can setup your ModelAdmin like so:

```
class ApplicationAdmin(model.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['text', 'applicant_name', 'applicant_email']
```

Comment: Yep... The accepted solution got edited while I was posting this. Good luck with your models!

Comment: this is probably the better way

Comment: The answer is fine. But can someone tell what actually happens when applicant_name is called during list display. Is their a separate db call made to retrieve applicant_name.

Comment: I don't actually know what the admin does anymore. To answer a question like that, [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest) is your friend. Even if it does make separate calls, you can probably leverage [select-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [prefetch-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) somehow, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to display it in list:

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    email = models.CharField(...)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s <%s>" % (self.name, self.email)

class ApplicationAdmin(model.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['text', 'applicant']
```

---

Answer to your comment

> but would like to have each field as a new line/row in the admin, not as a string.

Not sure if it is the best solution availabe but it will work:

```
class Application(models.Model):

    @property
    def applicant__name(self):
        return self.applicant.name

    # or maybe:

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('applicant__'):
            return gettattr(self.applicant, 
                            name[len('applicant__'):])
        raise AttributeError()

class ApplicationAdmin(model.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['text', 'applicant__name']
```

Comment: Will work as a alternative if there is not another solution, but would like to have each field as a new line/row in the admin, not as a string. Thanks for your answer, deeply appriciated.

Comment: Did not try your "maybe" solution. But the other one works like a charm, even without "property".