# How to display few fields from another model instead of one <select> field in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models linked one-to-many relationships:

```
ModelA:
field_1
..
field_n

ModelB:
some_field = ...
field = ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

What I need to do so that when opening an entry of ModelB in Admin site, other then all ModelB fields, all fields of ModelA are displayed instead of  field?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field) might help

Comment: I think it's answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868063/display-parent-fields-in-childs-admin-list-display

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BrianDestura Thank you for your help. Your comment was helpful to me.