# Django admin List Display + ForeignKey = Empty Change List

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-admin

I've got a weird problem in django admin `list_display`. Whenever I add a foreign key to a `list_display` the whole change list view goes blank showing only the total no of entries.

**models.py:**

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    org_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=288)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.org_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'organization'

class Server(models.Model):
    server_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    server_name = models.CharField(max_length=135,verbose_name="Server Name")
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization,verbose_name="Organization")   

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.server_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'server'
```

**admin.py:**

```
class ServerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('server_name','org') 
admin.site.register(Server,ServerAdmin)
```

Now I'd expect this code to show me the organization name in the `ChangeList View`, But instead I get this:

[image: empty changelist :(]

If I remove the `org` in the `list_display` of `ServerAdmin` class, I get this:

[image: change list with data :(]

I didn't modify the template or override any `ModelAdmin` methods. I'm using Mysql(5.1.58) as my database that comes with ubuntu 11.10 repository.

I'll be really glad if I could a get a sloution for this problem guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `models.py` I see `TlxServer` and in `admin.py` just `Server`. Is that a typo?

Comment: You don't need to define a AutoField. Django automatically creates a primary key for each table.

Comment: @jcollado: That's a typo :P its suppose to   be 'Server`

Comment: @dan-klasson: I got the models from a legacy database. I ran `inspectdb` and got the models and I got `IntegerField` for primary keys, So I changed them to `AutoFiled`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I second **Stefano** on the fact that `null=True, blank=True` is to be added. But, I think you only need to add it to the `org_name` field of the `Organization` model. That should make your way through. It has to be done because you have run `inspectdb` to create models from your legacy DB. And probably the `organization` table in the DB has an empty string stored. So, adding the above would allow the Admin to have a blank field/column displayed.

Moreover, you can also try using [callbacks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) in situations where you don't want to make changes to your model definition like the above.

Comment: Alright! Had a similar situation with another model like `Organization` which had a `ForeignKey` to `User`. Thanks to you and the `django-debug-toolbar` Zero'd on `INNER JOINS` causing whole problem. `inspectdb` doesn't specify `null=True,balnk=True` and I was too lazy ;) to cross check models and the database. Thanks man I owe you one for solving this mysterious looking problem.

Comment: Anytime Pannu. All are here to learn and I too have learnt from your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `null=True, blank=True` to all your model fields.

Usually django admin will silenty fail (thus show no records in the list) if the row does not validate the model constraints.

Answer (score 2):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/163968/1104941

Does the following work for you?

admin.py:

```
class ServerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('server_name','org__org_name') 
admin.site.register(Server,ServerAdmin)
```

Comment: I tried your solution, although strange as it may sound, it didn't seem to work. It kept popping an error `'org__org_name' is not a callable or an attribute of 'ServerAdmin' or found in the model 'Server'.` thanks anyways man.

Comment: You can't use terms that span relationships in list_display, which could be very helpful. A workaround is to define a method in the ModelAdmin subclass that returns the value you are looking for, and add that method's name to list_display.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it like this (using your example):

```
class ServerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('server_name', 'get_org') 

    def get_org(self, obj):
        return obj.org.org_name

    get_org.short_description = 'Org'

admin.site.register(Server,ServerAdmin)
```