# django admin list display of foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Various other posts on stack have looked at how to "properly" include a foreignkey in list_display, which enables sorting, etc.

However, I am not interested in that. I just want to display the unicode of the foreignkey field.

From the django docs:

```
A few special cases to note about list_display:

If the field is a ForeignKey, Django will display the __unicode__() of the related object.
```

I had this working previously, but since I last checked the django admin, it is no longer displaying any entries at all if the list_display includes a foreignkey field. Once the foreignkey field is removed from list_display, the entries are once again displaying.

I obviously updated something minor that caused this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this may be due to a DB issue storing the foreignkey info as an empty string.

As I am still in development, I simply dropped the table. However, I welcome discussion and answers on how to fix this without dropping the table.

[Django admin List Display + ForeignKey = Empty Change List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941857/django-admin-list-display-foreignkey-empty-change-list?lq=1)