# python django list_display on related inlines

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can “list_display” in a Django ModelAdmin display attributes of ForeignKey fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field)

I want to show some information on the admin list view of a model which comes from another, related model.

```
class Identity(models.Model):
  blocked = models.BooleanField()
  ...

class Person(models.Model):
  modelARef = OneToOneField("Identity", primary_key=True)
  descr     = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  name      = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

The User should be able to add/edit "Person" on the admin page. As there ist no support for reverse inlining I have to show "Identity" on the admin page and then inline "Person".
"Identity" only contains additional information to "Person" which should be visible on the admin page.

Now when I have a admin page for "Identity" how can I show fields from the "Person"-model on the list_display of "Identity"?

regards

EDIT: I can add some functions to "Identity" which query the related "Person" and return the needed value but if I do that there is no possibility to sort that column.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a `list_display` to add custom columns. I'd also advise updating the `get_queryset()` to make sure the related objects are only fetched on one query, instead of causing a query per row.

```
class IdentityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('blocked', 'person_name')

    def person_name(self, object):
        return object.person.name

    person_name.short_description = _("Person name")

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Prefetch related objects
        return super(IdentityAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).select_related('person')
```

Comment: It seems that the function to update the queryset should be `get_queryset` instead of `queryset` per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can create a method that prints out what you want, and add the method name to list_display. See [docs on list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: Yes, I can create a method that prints out what I want but than the columns won't be sortable (as I wrote in my post)