# Django: programatic fields in inlines

Tags: python, django

Expanding from this question: [Can "list_display" in a Django ModelAdmin display attributes of ForeignKey fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field), could it be possible to do something like this:

```
class MyModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model  = MyModel
    extra  = 1
    fields = ('my_field',)

    def my_field(self, obj):
        return obj.one_to_one_link.my_field
```

If something like this were possible, it would solve most of my current Django problems, but the code above does not work: Django (rightly) complains that `my_field` is not present in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but you must also add `my_field` to your `MyModelInline` class's `readonly_fields` attribute.

```
fields = ('my_field',)
readonly_fields = ('my_field',)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields):

> The fields option, unlike list_display, may only contain names of fields on the model or the form specified by form. It may contain callables only if they are listed in readonly_fields.

If you need the field to be editable, you should be able to do that with a custom form but it takes more work to process it.

Comment: Thank you! I must have missed that part of the docs. I was about to start a whole thing with proxy models and custom fields. Thanks for your help!