# how to “list_display” in a Django ModelAdmin display attributes of ForeignKey fields?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, admin

I've got the exact same problem than him : [Can "list_display" in a Django ModelAdmin display attributes of ForeignKey fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field)

**I want to see the question on the answer admin.**
I did the same thing than in the answer but got this error:

```
'Answer' object has no attribute 'question'
```

here is my code(question can have many possible answer):

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question')
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

my admin:

```
class AnswerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Answer
    list_display = ['answer', 'get_question', ]

    def get_question(self, obj):
        return obj.question.question


admin.site.register(Answer, AnswerAdmin)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `tuple` instead of a `list` for `list_display`?

Comment: yes got the same error

Comment: Is that your actual code? It looks ok to me, so I'm not sure why you're getting that error.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why this wouldn't work, but an alternative solution would be to override the `__unicode__()` method in `Question` (or `__str__()` if you're using Python3), which is what is displayed when you include a `ForeignKey` field in `list_display`:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question')
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class AnswerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Answer
    list_display = ['answer', 'question', ]
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display