# Django: list_display( ) ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Now i could use list_display( ) to show the column **word** and **click_times** when using Click_Data models. The code is below:

```
# models.py
class Click_Data(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    click_times = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('word',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.word  

# admin.py
    class Click_DataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fieldsets = [
            ('Word',    {'fields': ['word']}),
            ('Number',  {'fields': ['click_times']}),
        ]
        list_display = ('word', 'click_times')
```

But i don't know how to use list_display( ) to show the column **word** and **click_times** when using the **User_Data models**(which is below).

```
# models.py
class User_Data(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    click_data = models.ForeignKey(Click_Data)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)

# admin.py
class User_DataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('User',    {'fields': ['user']}),
        ('Word',    {'fields': ['click_data']}),
    ]
    list_display = ('user', 'click_data')
```

I want to show the not only the **'word'** in `'click_data'` but also **'click_times'**, how could i achieve this?

Comment: Do you want those as two separate columns in the table, or just both together in one column eg "<word>: <click_times>"?

Comment: Maybe duplicated post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field

Comment: @DanielRoseman i want those as two separate columns. Could you teach me ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User_DataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = (..., 'get_click_times', 'get_word')

    def get_click_times(self, obj):
        return obj.click_data.click_times

    get_click_times.short_description = 'Click Times'

    def get_word(self, obj):
        return obj.click_data.word

    get_word.short_description = 'Word'
```

Comment: for `Django > 3.2` use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67746847/11605100