# Show inline model field in list_display

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.person_name
```

and

```
class Book(models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    book_year = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    book_email = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = ('BookInline',)
    list_display = ('person_name', ...)

class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    extra = 1
    max_num = 1
```

In `PersonAdmin` list_display, how can i show the inline model `Book` fields (title, name, email).

so when i access `Person` list of entries in django admin, i see:

`person name` `book name` `book year` `book email`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "list\_display" in a Django ModelAdmin display attributes of ForeignKey fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field)

Answer (score 6):

The `list_display` for the `PersonAdmin` is meant to display each person once. It doesn't really make sense to include attributes from the book model, because then you would have to include the person multiple times if they have more than one book.

Wouldn't it be better to include the person's name on the book's `list_display`?

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = ('BookInline',)
    list_display = ('person_name', 'book_name', 'book_email', 'book_year')

    def person_name(self, obj):
        return obj.link.person_name

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

Comment: the book will have only one entry, and the project doesn't need listing the books, only the Person with their book. 

In general yes it's better to use your solution, but the requirements of my project is different, and need to include the book details in person listing.

Comment: Yes, the book will have one entry. The problem is that each person can have more than one book. If you are displaying a person in the person admin, which book should you display? What should you display if no books exist for that person?

Comment: Each person can't have more than one book, since `max_num = 1` is specified in `BookAdmin`.

and to answer your question: even if there is multiple books, i want to show the 1st book. and if no books exist (which won't happen since it's required field) but i'll still display a string "No books" for example.

Comment: `max_num = 1` is only for the admin -- multiple books for the same person could still be added elsewhere. It is easy to add a person without a book - just create a person in the person admin. If you really have one person for each book, then you should use a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) instead of a foreign key.

Comment: I think the structure of your models is wrong, but if you want to add the fields to the `PersonAdmin`, then my answer shows you how to do it. Create methods e.g. `book_name` on your `PersonAdmin`, then include them in the person admin's `list_display`.

Comment: creating the method `book_name` with `return obj.book.book_title` giving the error `'Person' object has no attribute 'book'`.
What i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It doesn't have an attribute `book`, because the foreign key means each person can have multiple books. See the docs on [following relationships backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), you can use a callable to display your fields.

Edit (2021/03/21): the link to the 1.9 doc is not working anymore, but [the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/docs/ref/contrib/admin/index.txt#L529) is still available. I add the link to the [dev version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) too.

Comment: doc link is not working anymore (404 error ).@Linkid

Comment: Thanks! I've just edited the answer to add 2 links: the source of the doc for v1.9 (not maintained anymore) and the dev doc.

Answer (score 0):

```
class BookInline(admin.StackedInline):
   model = Book
   extra = 1
   max_num = 1
```

StackedInline will solve your problem