# How to do different data representation from model def __str__ in Admin and Templates

Tags: django, django-models

I need to display information in Admin from def **str**  like a 
self.name + self.last_name, but at the same time I need to show only name value in templates. How I can do it?

Now I see the same self.name + self.last_name for both

Comment: Just try `object.name` in templates.

Comment: There's a very good explanation on how to do this in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23747842/243925) to a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom method in your model for admin page and use `__str__` method for other things

```
def admin_name(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.last_name)

admin_name.short_description = 'Full name'
```

and just append this in `list_display` of your admin model representation in `admin.py`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to make the `__str__` method behave differently in different views.

If you don't want to use the `__str__` method in the templates, use the individual attributes instead:

```
{{ user.name }}
```