# Displaying foreign model fields in django admin as editable

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a Django Model with a Foreign key:

```
class Library:
  name=models.CharField()

class Book:
  title=models.CharField()
  library=models.ForeignKey(Library)
```

*models.py*

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  extra = 0
  fields = ['title', 'library__name'] # library__name not found

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

*admin.py*

In the admin, I want to display `Book` and show an **editable** field for `Library.name` in the `Book` view (not the other way around with inlines):

```
> Book
  * Title: "Foo"
  * Library Name: "Bar"
```

As readonly, it's easy (just creating a method in Book model returning the library name value) but I cannot make it work for editable fields, I tried using `fields=('title','library.name')` and  `fields=('title','library__name')` without success

Comment: Try to do like in [this post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field)

Answer (score 0):

You need an inline model admin:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Answer (score -2):

try to use `related_name` in models like that

`library=models.ForeignKey(Library, related_name="library")`

then use `fields=('title','library__name')` and it should work.

Comment: I cannot make it work this way. changing the related_name doesn't seems to change the behavior of `fields` in the `Book` view.

Comment: what is the error u get.. give us more details if possible

Comment: Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value: 
Unknown field(s) (library__name) specified for Book. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class BookAdmin.

It's the same error I was getting before

Comment: edit ur question and show the admin class u wrote please

Comment: u want this field to appear when adding an object or u want it to appear in the class page for listing items?

Comment: When adding/editing a Book I want all the data of the book + an editable field for the Library name