# How to show linked objects in Django Admin View?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

I have two models that are linked by a foreign key relationship:

```py
class A(models.Model):
    q1 = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    q2 = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    ... 

class B(models.Model):
    b = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    a = models.ForeignKey("A", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In my admin site I have the A model showing, and ideally would like to keep it that way.

Is there a way for me to within the individual A instances show the B instances? I have only been able to find solutions for the [reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480778/displaying-foreign-model-fields-in-django-admin-as-editable) (showing a dropdown of A instances in the individual B instances).

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: @iklinac Thank you. I misread/didn't fully understand that article initially, but your suggestion made me revisit it. If you put it as an answer, I can upvote and accept it.