# Access to model field through connected one

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.0

I have two models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("category", max_length=200, null=True)
    discount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("product", max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products", verbose_name="category")
```

How to show `discount` value in admin panel?

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'category', 'price', 'discount'] # not works
    list_filter = ['category', 'price']
    list_editable = ['price']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "list\_display" in a Django ModelAdmin display attributes of ForeignKey fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("product", max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField("price", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products", verbose_name="category")
    def discount_value(self):
        return self.category.discount
```