# Need to show related model specific field on admin changelist - Django 1.11

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(choices=ChoicesModel.MY_CHOICES, max_length=128, blnk=True, null=True)
```

I have a separate model with the choices, for a matter of reusability. That works well so far.

Now, on the admin view, I need to show these choices, but in another model's `list_display`. I have tried many things with no success.

These models are related with a `ForeignKey`.

So, specifically, I need the parent model `list_display`, to show the choice made on the child model related by the ForeignKey.

The `ForeignKey` is defined on the child model, so it is related to the parent with this `ForeignKey` field.

So, how can I read this choice made on the child object from the parent and show it on the `list_display` of it's parent?

I'm using Django 1.11

**EDIT**

So far, I've tried with this:

```
related = models.OneToOneField('ChildModel', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Then, on admin:

```
def get_child_status(self, obj):
    return obj.related.my_choice_field
get_child_status.short_description = 'Child status'
```

And, of course on my list_display:

```
list_display = ('field1', 'field2', 'get_child_status')
```

When I visit the `changelist` view of the Parent model it throws me:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'my_choice_field'
```

**EDIT 2**

This is the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 283, in lookup_field
f = _get_non_gfk_field(opts, name)
File "C:\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 317, in _get_non_gfk_field
field = opts.get_field(name)
File "C:\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 619, in get_field
raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: MyModel has no field named 'get_child_status'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "list\_display" in a Django ModelAdmin display attributes of ForeignKey fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field)

Comment: But I'm trying those solutions, it always says that the parent class doesn't have attribute (the onetoone field) which is non sense

Comment: Please update the question with some code and the traceback of the error that you are getting

Comment: Done, can you have a look? Thank You very much

Comment: Added the complete traceback, sorry

Comment: Your `get_child_status` assumes that `obj.related` always exists, which seems to be not the case. You need to add an existence check.