# Django list display of foreign key attribute that is boolean field using check or cross icons

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin

My problem is similar to this thread: [Can "list_display" in a Django ModelAdmin display attributes of ForeignKey fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field). I want to display a foreign key attribute from the list display. This attribute is a BooleanField. Normally, it would display a check or cross if the admin page is on the model itself containing the field. Such as this:

[image]

However when I reference this to other admin page.

```
class ProofOfPaymentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'reference_number', 'user', 'is_subscribed',)

    def is_subscribed(self, obj):
        return obj.user.is_subscribed
```

The return from the list display is the boolean values `True` or `False`.

[image]

How can I change this to display the icons check or cross similar from the above?

**Update 1:**
Result from first answer:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`format_html()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) method to return HTML code for displaying the checkmark or cross icon based on the Boolean value, following is an example:

```py
from django.utils.html import format_html

class ProofOfPaymentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'reference_number', 'user', 'is_subscribed',)
    
    def is_subscribed(self, obj):
        if obj.user.is_subscribed:
            return format_html('<span style="color:green">&#x2714;</span>') 
        else:
            return format_html('<span style="color:red">&#x2718;</span>') 
    is_subscribed.short_description = 'Subscribed?' # Set the column header
```

This will display a green checkmark icon for `True` values and a red cross icon for `False` values. The `format_html` method ensures that the HTML code is properly escaped to prevent any security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Hi @Sunderam Dubey, your answer is correct, that may be the way. Although, I get the wrong icons . I updated the thread which shows the icons you provided.

Comment: Upon digging in inspect the html. The icons came from staticfiles: `http://localhost:8000/static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg`

Comment: @Nikko You can modify the icons according to yourself (maybe see bootstrap code), I have not much knowledge of icons, you can do it :) Do you also get a cross icon which you need?

Comment: @Nikko Do you want a red color cross icon?

Comment: I did got a red cross, but not the django staticfile default :)